# How to change language in Actions in google web simulator?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I have created an agent in French in API.AI. After that when I go to the web simulator the other langugaes are greyed out.
[image]

Even the things I typed in french are pronounced in english.Does any one know what is the root cause for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that currently only english (both US and GB) is supported.
In the future you will be able to use the other languages.

Comment: Today google Home is available in France. Hope simulator will be support french soon...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only English (en-US, and sorta en-UK) are supported for Actions on Google. Additional language support was announced at I/O and should be available later this year. It looks like the Simulator has gotten some changes recently to anticipate these updates.